# ListView does not show DB items

Tags: android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I worked all day to show my items what are in my database, but I can't.
I've got a one table database with some items and I want to display them in ListActivity.

Here is my code:

**Layout (activity_cars):**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnNewCar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnNewCar" />

<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dip"  >
</ListView>
```

**ListActivity:**

```
public class CarsActivity extends ListActivity {

private CarListAdapter carListAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cars);

    CarDbLoader carDbLoader = new CarDbLoader(getApplicationContext());
    carDbLoader.open();

    Cursor c = carDbLoader.fetchAll();
    c.moveToFirst();

    carListAdapter = new CarListAdapter(this, c);
    setListAdapter(carListAdapter);
}
```

}

**ListAdapter:**

```
public class CarListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public CarListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.car_list_row, null);
    bindView(row, context, cursor);
    return row;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    Car car = CarDbLoader.getCarByCursor(cursor);
    TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rowText);
    tv.setText(car.toString());
}
```

}

I am sure that I've got items in the table...but I really don't know what's reason of this activity doesn't show items.
Please help to find out and make the correct source.

Thanks nad Marry Chrostmas!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you set listview's height to 0dip?

```
<ListView 
   android:id="@android:id/list"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="0dip"  > // Why 0 dip? Try "fill_parent" or "match_parent"
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call bindView() here any way? I think it's not necessary and may cause some fault.

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.car_list_row, null);
    bindView(row, context, cursor);//Why do you call bindView() here?
    return row;
}
```